# Use javascript variables in Rails view helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Using jqGrid I want to generate delete links for each row in the grid. The standard way to do this is to add the links in the gridComplete callback like shown below:

```
gridComplete: function() {                                                                                                                                      
  var ids = jQuery("#jobs_table").jqGrid('getDataIDs');                                                                                                         
  for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){                                                                                                                              
    var cl = ids[i];                                                                                                                                            
    be = '<%= link_to(image_tag("delete.gif", :border=>0, :size=>"20x22", :alt => "delete"),⋅                                                                   
              { :action => 'destroy', :id => 'cl', :method => :delete}, :class => 'ajax')  -%>';                                                        
    jQuery("#jobs_table").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{workflow_state:be});                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                             
},
```

Using getDataIDs I get a list of IDs that I can use to generate the delete links. The problem is that this is a javascript call that results in a javascript variable.

The question is how can I use this variable "cl" inside rails link_to view helper?

Comment: I know I can simply write the whole html using the javascript variables inside but I would prefer using the rails helpers if possible.

Comment: Is link_to is a global JavaScript function? It seems to me also, that you have some problems with escaping of "'" character in assigning of `be` variable.

Comment: link_to is a Rails view helper. The problem is that the javascript variable cl is passed as a string to the rails function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting to add a delete button to each row?
If so why dont you just return a column called delete then add custom formatter in your javascript that returns the button.

[Custom Formater](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)

Comment: That is what I am doing but instead of a formatter I simply add the link html code in the created_at column.